# Is there a way to break a pandas column with categories to seperate true or false columns with the category name as the column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with the following column:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,1,2,2,2,0,1,0]})
```

and i want:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"0": [0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1],"1": [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0],"2": [0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0]})
```

is there an elegant way of doing this using a oneliner.

**NOTE**

- I can do this using df['0'] = df['A'].apply(find_zeros)
- I dont mind if 'A' is included in the final.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
df2 = pd.get_dummies(df.A)
print (df2)
   0  1  2
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
5  0  0  1
6  1  0  0
7  0  1  0
8  1  0  0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [50]: df.A.astype(str).str.get_dummies()
Out[50]:
   0  1  2
0  0  1  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  0  1
4  0  0  1
5  0  0  1
6  1  0  0
7  0  1  0
8  1  0  0
```